# Upload plugin folder in to wordpress directory in google conpute engine VM instance from my PC

Tags: wordpress, recursion, file-upload, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I was searching everywhere and couldnt able to find out how to upload a folder to my wordpress directory in copute engine VM. I just want to  upload a modified plugin to my wp plugin directory in google compute engine VM. Some one please help

Answer (score 0):

You can not upload folder directly to a VM instance.
You should compress your folder first then you will be able to upload to your VM.

Their is many way you can transfer files to your VM instance, here is the documentations [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files). However, this is my favorite method [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files#linux).

Keep in mind that your uploaded files will be located in your /home/ directory. At this point you can move your file and unzip in the directory of your choice.

Voila!

Comment: I managed to upload plugin folder using WinSCP. First you need to set up ssh connection using PuTTY and then it is possible to SFTP.